# How can I select specific number of last child using CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

For example, there are total 12 elements.
I want to apply my style only on last n (1, 2, 3...) numbers of child of total 12 elements; how can I do this?

Comment: Post your code so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Solved by Joseph. Anyway, here is the code:
&:not(:nth-last-child(-n+#{$column_number}))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the css pseudo-class `:nth-last-child` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child))

Just use a negative n value and add the index from the end (represents number of elements)

```
 .parentClass > * :nth-last-child ( -n + 3 ) {
    /* CSS here for last 3 elements */
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/evm0mg8j/

Comment: Problem solved; thanks!
&:not(:nth-last-child(-n+#{$column_number}))